# Python 3.4.2 - Stuck on Assignment (List)

Tags: python, python-3.4

Okay my code works but then breaks at the end. If anyone can assist me I would greatly appreciate it.

Write a program named celebrities.py that uses a list to store the names of some notable celebrities. Use a loop to prompt the user for the names and to add them to the list. When the user enters "done" the loop should stop. The program should then output the number of celebrities entered. Finally, the program should use another loop to display the celebrity names, each on its own line, and "done" should NOT be in the celebrities list.

```
lst = []

while(1):
    name = input("Please enter a celebrities name, when your finished enter Done:") # This will prompt the end user to enter a celebrities name. 

    if name == "Done":# if the end user types Done with a capital D, it will end stop the program.
        break;
    else:
        lst.append(name) # This will add the name to the list.

# print names in loop
for c in celebrities_list:
    print(c)

print("You input the following {} celebrities!".format((list)))
```

Comment: So where is it broken?

Comment: What is `celebrities_list`? Shouldnt it be `lst`?

Comment: It will allow for me to add the names, but when I type Done it throws an error message. I will try and run again.

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: Were you ever going to share the error message with us?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 Assignments\Chapter 7\celebrities.py", line 12, in <module>
    for c in celebrities_list:
NameError: name 'celebrities_list' is not defined
>>>

Comment: It should be: `for c in lst: print(c)`

Answer (score 2):

I think your end part should be as follows:

```
# print names in loop
for c in lst: 
    print(c)

print("You input the following {:d} names of celebrities:  {:s}".format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))
```

Comment: I got it working now, but there is still one outstanding part. I am needing the output to count the total number of names entered.

Comment: @ATLbound2015. `print("You input the following {:d} names of celebrities:  {:s}".format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))`